# Handling UserIntent in Flutter by calling eventSink from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I have a Flutter application with iOS native plugin implemented in Swift. My goal is to call `eventSink` from within `AppDelegate` as part of `UserIntent` handling.  I have tried following to no success:

### Attempt 1

During the `FlutterPlugin.register` callback, I am also registering plugin instance as application delegate.  Code below:

```
public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(....)
    let eventChannel = FlutterEventChannel(....)

    let instance = SwiftMyPlugin()
    eventChannel.setStreamHandler(instance)
    registrar.addApplicationDelegate(instance) // <--- Register as application delegate here
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: methodChannel)
}
```

Unfortunately, this has no effect for `UserIntent` handling callbacks.  Example, consider following implementation as part of `UIApplicationDelegate` by `SwiftMyPlugin` class.

```
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // eventSink!("...");  <--- Trying to achieve this
  }
```

### Attempt 2

Of-course when I move above callback within `AppDelegate` class it works just fine.  Example, consider following within `AppDelegate` class:

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
  // eventSink!("...");  <--- Trying to achieve this
}
```

But here the issue is how do I get access to `eventSink` initialized by `SwiftMyPlugin` class.

### Attempt 2.1

I tried to declare `eventSink` as a global variable but that runs into `inaccessible due to protection level`

### Attempt 2.2

`Flutter` registrar provides a `publish` method which can be used to share an object with external code.  I tried exposing instance of `SwiftMyPlugin` using `registrar.publish` method, but I wasn't able to access it variable on the other side within `AppDelegate`.

### Question

Can someone provide pointers to how can I pass intent data back to dart land, once the app has opened up via user intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity here is how to get reference to the plugin within AppDelegate:

1. Publish plugin instance during registration as `registrar.publish(instance)`
2. Access the object from AppDelegate using `valuePublished(byPlugin: "MyPlugin") as! SwiftMyPlugin`

Call the public method to handle incoming user intent data.